# Access file content within an Azure Dev Ops/VSTS artifact using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-artifacts

I am looking to get the contents of a file I pushed as an artifact to Azure DevOps

I was able to get a json response with a URL to the artifact zip by using this API

```
https://dev.azure.com/uifabric/cd9e4e13-b8db-429a-9c21-499bf1c98639/_apis/build/builds/8838/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=5.0
```

However, what I really want is the contents of a file called `bundlesizes.json` within this zip.

I did come across the Get File API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20file?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) which mentions an API as follows

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&fileId={fileId}&fileName={fileName}&api-version=5.0
```

I tried replacing it as follows

```
https://dev.azure.com/uifabric/fabricpublic/_apis/build/builds/8838/artifacts?artifactName=drop&fileId=bundlesizes.json&fileName=bundlesizes.json&api-version=5.0
```

However, I get this error
[image]

I think what I am missing is the `fileId` field, where I am not aware what needs to go in. The documentation says `fileId` is the *The primary key for the file*. However, I don't know where I can find it.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft doesn't have complete documentation on how to get FileID.

You can take a different approach and download the file using below API. You can get the ContainerID through GET build details.

> ```
> https://collectionurl/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/resources/Containers/${containerid}?itempath=drop
> ```

Comment: how I get container id?

Comment: @gsscoder "URL/_apis/build/builds/{buildid}/artifacts"
you have the container ID on resource.data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you mean here: https://resources.azure.com/?

Comment: @gsscoder: Did you find an answer for your question above? I'm trying to do the same and wondering how to do this.

Comment: @MAK Are you able to get the API response for below?
<TeamProjectURL>/_apis/build/builds/<BuildID>/artifacts

Comment: @MAK I found how to download the whole artifact as zip archive. You shuold use the **builds** endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) Than add `'&%24format=zip` Without this you'll get just some JSON that describes the artifact. Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1):

[View my blog post to see how this is done here!](https://alexoswald.com/2023/10/07/azure-devops-artifacts)

Let us start by hitting the [Artifacts - Get Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-artifact) so we can get some info about the artifact.

**Request**

```
https://dev.azure.com/oswaldtechnologies/add3132d-b1ce-4519-8299-4e67eecad1f5/_apis/build/builds/703/artifacts?artifactName=TestArtifact
```

**Response**

```json
{
    "id": 322,
    "name": "TestArtifact",
    "source": "12f1170f-54f2-53f3-20dd-22fc7dff55f9",
    "resource": {
        "type": "PipelineArtifact",
        "data": "973C2055701973A0FDFB695031EE3F9E7A91741016CA639E9D21ECCD1B387E9B01",
        "properties": {
            "RootId": "DC04A61FBB2E879A10EE8BA01B28B4623140546805A968AB2B491B2EE1BD2E4102",
            "artifactsize": "28",
            "HashType": "DEDUPNODEORCHUNK"
        },
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/oswaldtechnologies/add3132d-b1ce-4519-8299-4e67eecad1f5/_apis/build/builds/703/artifacts?artifactName=TestArtifact&api-version=7.1",
        "downloadUrl": "https://artprodeus21.artifacts.visualstudio.com/A3e090689-466b-408e-a12e-87c169eff347/add3132d-b1ce-4519-8299-4e67eecad1f5/_apis/artifact/cGlwZWxpbmVhcnRpZmFjdDovL29zd2FsZHRlY2hub2xvZ2llcy9wcm9qZWN0SWQvYWRkMzEzMmQtYjFjZS00NTE5LTgyOTktNGU2N2VlY2FkMWY1L2J1aWxkSWQvNzAzL2FydGlmYWN0TmFtZS9UZXN0QXJ0aWZhY3Q1/content?format=zip"
    }
}
```

Notice `resource.data`. This is actually the `fileId`. And this is what the documentation does not mention. We use the `fileId` of the actual artifact, to get the artifacts manifest contents. The manifest contains an array of all items in the artifact, including their file path and file id. So now lets hit [Aritfacts - Get File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-file) with the artifacts file id to get the manifest. Oddly, you must add `fileId` **and** `fileName` to the query, even though what you set `fileName` to doesn't matter. For this example, I'm going to call it `manifest.json`, because well, that's what it is.

**Request**

```
https://dev.azure.com/oswaldtechnologies/add3132d-b1ce-4519-8299-4e67eecad1f5/_apis/build/builds/703/artifacts?artifactName=TestArtifact&fileId=973C2055701973A0FDFB695031EE3F9E7A91741016CA639E9D21ECCD1B387E9B01&fileName=manifest.json
```

**Response**

```json
{
    "manifestFormat": "1.1.0",
    "items": [
        {
            "path": "/test1.txt",
            "blob": {
                "id": "D21C967E56201F344B44EE00F537263C3503AEB13931F99754F9E78E14E6C90C01",
                "size": 14
            }
        },
        {
            "path": "/test2.txt",
            "blob": {
                "id": "FE2A48E456C37C7BAF1F86D724E2C2B30658AA1A899201D61E23CE59A333A63801",
                "size": 14
            }
        }
    ],
    "manifestReferences": []
}
```

Now we can hit [Aritfacts - Get File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-file) once more. This time let us get the contents of `test1.txt`. Again, it does not matter what you set `fileName` too, as long as the `fileId` matches the `blob.id` of the file you want to download.

**Request**

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/builds/703/artifacts?artifactName=TestArtifact&fileId=D21C967E56201F344B44EE00F537263C3503AEB13931F99754F9E78E14E6C90C01&fileName=test1.txt
```

**Response**

```
Test string 1
```